# logback.xml is not being picked by websphere 9.0.5.X

Tags: java, jboss, websphere, log4j2, logback

The Websphere is not picking up logback.xml. On the other hand, if I'm switching to log4j2.xml, it's being picked up automatically. Not sure why the server logging config is taking priority over the logback.

My configuration for **logback**:

logs are being written in the AppSrv01\logs\server1\system_out.log irrespective of logger level and appenders config in the logback.xml

dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml: No luck with both file/console appender

```
<configuration>

  <property name="HOME_LOG" value="logs/app.log"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/archived/app%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

  <logger name="com.sample.package" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>
  
  <root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Notes:

1. classloader order is set to "parent last".
2. my application is using the slf4j logger.
3. the Same logback configuration is working in JBoss after excluding the logging subsystem in JBoss-deployment-structure.xml(Not able to find the same for WebSphere).

Failure attempts:

1. bringing out the logback.xml and zip it as a jar, and pointing as a shared library
2. using slf4j-simple instead of sl4j-jdk14, logs have been stopped writing completely.

My **log4j2** config, just for comparison:

dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml: both console/file appenders are working

```
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <logger name="com.sample.package" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>
        <Root level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```